# Wordpress Search Regex plugin not matching greater than symbol

Tags: search-regex

I am using the [Search Regex plugin](http://urbangiraffe.com/plugins/search-regex/) for Wordpress. I have it matching all of my regex except for the literal ">", which it never correctly matches.

Answer (score 0):

The answer was to use the HTML special character, `&gt;` in my pattern, rather than an actual `>`.  Every time I submitted the search, `&gt;` was replaced by `>`, so I had to keep changing it back to the escaped version. I assume this could be true for any [character represented in HTML by a special character](https://www.utexas.edu/learn/html/spchar.html).